# Jquery ajax onclick submit all ajax to php and return something

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a function that will post all the checkboxes inside a form to a php page. The php page will do some processing and will return a a value. The value will be shown to a div i set up called results. Every check they make will post the form and return something. (the value is gonna tell the user what else to check or what they must do to complete the form properly)

My code only submit the one checkbox that was check not the other checkbox that was check before that.

Can someone please help...

Thanks!!

Form looks like this with many more checkboxes.

```
<input name="picture[1][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=1>
<input name="picture[1][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=2>
<input name="picture[2][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=1>
<input name="picture[2][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=2>
<input name="picture[3][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=1>
<input name="picture[3][categories][]" type="checkbox" value=2>
<div id="result">
```

My jquery function looks like

```
$("input").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#result").html('');

    var values = $("checkbox").serialize();

    $.ajax({ url: 'http://example.com/check.php',
         data: values,
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      // alert(output);
                       $("#result").html(output);
                  }
    });


});
```

Comment: put all checkboxes in a form and try `$("#form").serialize()` on form. and 2nd thing, I think it will send checkboxes as `on` only which is checked. I think this might help you.

Comment: 2nd thing I don't understand is why there are duplicate checkboxes, I mean all are twice, with same name and value?

Comment: Yeah fixed the first thing and let me try that the 2nd thing that might do the trick

Comment: You are welcome. I have posted comments as answer so you can set it as right answer and  set the question as resolved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all checkboxes in a form and try $("#form").serialize() on form.

And 2nd thing, I think it will send checkboxes as on only which is checked. I think this might help you.

3rd thing I don't understand is why there are duplicate checkboxes, I mean all are twice, with same name and value?

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach is to use client site validation before sending your form to a php script. That way your not continually making server calls whenever the user presses submit, only when the data is valid.

Use a submit button that calls a validation script, and if successful sends the data to your php script. 
e.g.

your html

```
<button id="submit" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
```

in your js/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if(validateForm){

        //send form to php script for further processing
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $.post('yourScript.php',formData,formSent);//your script, form data, callback function
        }//end if
    });//end click funciton

});//end document ready

function validateForm(){
    $('form').find('input').each(function() {
    //validate each input item in your form
    //highlight any input errors
    }//end each
   // and return true or false based on the results
   return result;
}//end validateForm

function formSent(data){
    alert('Form has been sent!');
    //display returned data from php script into your results div
    $('#yourDiv').html(data);

}//end formSent
```

Hope this helps...